# Out of bounds subscript error

Tags: r

I am working on a simple matrix for Singular Value Decomposition 10x10 with all entries zeros. I'd like to add a coin flip to this matrix and run SVD. The code is below:

```html
# Simple Example 

set.seed(1234) 
par(mar=rep(0.2,4))
dataMatrix = matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10)

dataMatrix

getMatrix = dataMatrix*0
getMatrix

svd1 = svd(getMatrix)
svd1

par(mfrow=c(1,5))

image(t(getMatrix)[,nrow(getMatrix):1], col='blue')
plot(svd1$d,xlab='Column',ylab='Singular Values', pch=19, col='red')


## Add a pattern to the data set , flipping a coin 

set.seed(78910)
for (i in 1:40){
  coinFlip1 = rbinom(1,size=1, prob=0.5)
  coinFlip2 = rbinom(1,size=1,prob=0.5)
  
  if (coinFlip1){
    getMatrix[i,]=getMatrix[i,]+rep(c(0,5),each=5)
  }
  if (coinFlip2){
    getMatrix[i,]=getMatrix[i,]+rep(c(0,5),each=5)
  }
}

hh = hclust(dist(getMatrix))
getMatrixOrdered= getMatrix[hh$order,]
```

## When I run the program in R, it gives me an error below:

Error in getMatrix[i, ] : subscript out of bounds

I know the bounds are out of order, so how can I fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in 1:40){
```

substitute for

```
for (i in 1:10){
```